# How to Display Title Dynamically in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a Report in which needs to display Header Like

**Month Month-name** here
eg : Month February

Month-name is the dynamic which is current month -1

How can i write this in Expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
="Month " & Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -1, Today()), "MMMM")
```

will work:

[image]

[image]

[image]